# ForceTouch: control the amplitude of the feedback

Tags: swift, macos-catalina, appkit, xcode11.5

I'm coding an macOS app with Xcode (11.5 under MacOS Catalina) that triggers an haptic feedback on my Macbook Pro's trackpad with the command `NSHapticFeedbackManager.defaultPerformer.perform(NSHapticFeedbackManager.FeedbackPattern.generic, performanceTime: .now);`.

**Problem:** the haptic feedback is too weak to be properly perceived, and I'd like to increase its strength. Ideally, I'd like to have the same feedback that when a click is detected by the system.

**Tested:** I've tried to change parameters like `pattern` or `performanceTime`, but the feedback is not improved (and sometimes not perceivable anymore).

Is there a solution to increase the strength of this haptic feedback?
Thanks!